# How do I fix the terminator screen going black?

Tags: terminator

When multiple tabs are open in terminator and the window is in focus contents of only the active/focussed tab are visible and all the remaining tabs simply go black. The processes in these tabs aren't stopped but the logs/commands/etc are not visible.

When the focus is switched to different app window all the tabs in the terminator window go black. Similarly when the right click action is performed in the terminator window all the tabs go black.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Laptop model: Lenovo Thinkpad P1 (Gen 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had/have the same problem, but with split terminal. Removing the Terminator config file (~/.config/terminator/config) and a reboot solved my problem - probably only temporary.